# How do I programmatically change CSS class rules

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following CSS and need to programmatically update it after clicking a button but I cannot figure out how.

This is the initial CSS

```
.hoverable:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

I need the class to have the following CSS after clicking the button.

```
.hoverable:hover { 
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Programmatically updating css should be a last resort.  You can define that second bit of css with an additional classname, and add that classname to your element, or some ancestor element, when the button is clicked.

Comment: I really needed to be able to alter the rules of this specific class since it's injected from an external source (that I have no control over). It's coming from Quasar specifically and this CSS has been causing me issues. If it's not possible then I guess I'll have to reverse-engineer their product and make a copy of their CSS classes to use in my application.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify style inside `pseudo-class` but you can change css variable.

```js
const hoverable = document.querySelectorAll('.hoverable')

const button = document.querySelector('#button')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  hoverable.forEach((el) => {
    el.style.setProperty("--hoverColor", "blue")
  })
})
```

```css
.hoverable {
  --hoverColor: red;
}

.hoverable:hover {
  color: var(--hoverColor);
}
```

```html
<p class="hoverable">foo bar</p>
<p class="hoverable">foo bar 2</p>

<button id="button">press me</button>
```

Comment: It is also possible to change classes

Comment: This is a good solution but unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue. I really needed to be able to alter the rules of a class because it's injected from an external source (that I have no control over). Since it's not possible then I guess I'll have to reverse-engineer this external product and make a copy of their CSS classes to use in my application. –

Comment: element.style = "css string"?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use `document.querySelectorAll()` and loop over the results. There are methods to change the [`CSSStyleRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule) object itself, but they are convoluted and hard to read.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const els = document.querySelectorAll('.hoverable');
  for (const el of els) {
    el.style.color = 'blue';
  }
});
```

```css
.hoverable {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<p class="hoverable">Some text.</p>

<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```